# Getting input in a String in cpp

Tags: c++

Hello I want to get some input in a string in cpp and I am getting and error. Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>


int main() {

    using namespace std;

    string name;
    
    cout << "Type your name:";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Your name is: " << name;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am building the project and I get this error:

```
Test1.cpp:10:6: error: invalid operands to binary expression
```

It is this line: `cout << "Type your name:";`

What am I missing here ? It is the first time when I am using c++

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CXkntsWhUmqWDKhi). Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also make sure what you are compiling is what you think you are compiling.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<iostream>` does not include `<string>`. Hence, you also need to include `<string>` in order to use `std::string`.

```cpp
#include <iostream> // for std::cout, std::cin
#include <string> // for std::string
```